# Add mouse speed multiplier to score

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a very beginner coder so please forgive how rudimentary this code is. I'm trying to make a simple game where you accrue points while the mouse is down with a multiplier for mouse speed. Currently my mouse speed function is not working correctly, it seems to be a fixed variable at the moment. If anybody could point out what I've done wrong I'd be very appreciative. Sorry if there is already an answer for this, I searched the archives and didn't find anything that quite answered my question.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UpdateScoreOnMousePress : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text scoreText;
    public int score;

    public Vector3 mouseDelta = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 lastPos = Vector3.zero;
    float mouseSpeed;

    float timeToGo = 0.5f;

    //Initialization
    void Start()
    {
        timeToGo = Time.fixedTime;
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Checks if it has been 0.5 seconds since last call
        if (Time.fixedTime > timeToGo)
        {
            //Updates score on mouse down
            scoreText.text = "Score: " + score + (int)mouseSpeed*0.1;

            //Start mousePosition
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                mouseDelta = Input.mousePosition;
            }

            else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                mouseDelta = Input.mousePosition - lastPos;

                score++;

                //Shows mouse position and magnitude in console
                Debug.Log("delta X : " + mouseDelta.x);
                Debug.Log("delta Y : " + mouseDelta.y);
                Debug.Log("delta distance : " + mouseDelta.magnitude);

                //Updates mousePosition
                lastPos = Input.mousePosition;

                //Updates mouseSpeed
                mouseSpeed = mouseDelta.magnitude / Time.deltaTime;
            }

            //Updates timeToGo
            timeToGo = Time.fixedTime + 0.5f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you press your left mouse button the code will register it from the "if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))" the "else if" after is then never run, since it also checks if the mouse button is pressed and therefor you do never run the code inside your else if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are checking upon if the primary mouse button is pressed twice. From both

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
```

and

```
else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
```

Furthermore you will have to also update the last mouse position through each iteration, where as of now you do it only when the mouse button is pressed, which is not incorrect but you will have to do it when the button is not pressed aswell.

I do believe your code could be fixed if you changed it to the following:

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Checks if it has been 0.5 seconds since last call
        if (Time.fixedTime > timeToGo)
        {
            //Updates score on mouse down
            scoreText.text = "Score: " + score + (int)mouseSpeed*0.1;    

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {

                mouseDelta = Input.mousePosition - lastPos;

                score++;

                //Shows mouse position and magnitude in console
                Debug.Log("delta X : " + mouseDelta.x);
                Debug.Log("delta Y : " + mouseDelta.y);
                Debug.Log("delta distance : " + mouseDelta.magnitude);

                //Updates mouseSpeed
                mouseSpeed = mouseDelta.magnitude / Time.deltaTime;
            }
            lastPos = Input.mousePosition;
            //Updates timeToGo
            timeToGo = Time.fixedTime + 0.5f;
        }
    }
```

This does not solve your issue with distributing a score based on the distance moved, but you should be able to implement this by using mouseDelta.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice everyone. Here is the final working code for anyone who may need it in the future. Adjust the values for the speed multipliers if you desire, as well as how often the fixed update is called.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UpdateScoreWhileMousePressed : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 mouseDelta = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 lastPos = Vector3.zero;

    public float mouseSpeed;

    public Text scoretext;
    public int score;

    public float timeToGo;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        timeToGo = Time.fixedTime;
        mouseDelta = Input.mousePosition;
        lastPos = Input.mousePosition;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {



    }

    // Update is called every 0.2 seconds
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(Time.fixedTime > timeToGo)
        {

            //Update mouseDelta
            mouseDelta = Input.mousePosition - lastPos;

            //Calculate mouseSpeed
            mouseSpeed = mouseDelta.magnitude / Time.deltaTime;

            scoretext.text = "Score: " + score;

            Debug.Log("Speed: " + mouseSpeed);
            Debug.Log("Score: " + score);

            //If the mouse is being pressed the score will increase by 1 every call
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {

                if(mouseSpeed <= 1000)
                {
                    score += 1;
                }

                //And receive multipliers for faster speed
                else if(mouseSpeed > 1000 & mouseSpeed < 2000)
                {
                    score += 1 * 2;
                }

                else if(mouseSpeed >= 2000 & mouseSpeed < 4000)
                {
                    score += 1 * 3;
                }

                else if(mouseSpeed >=4000 & mouseSpeed < 8000)
                {
                    score += 1 * 4;
                }

                else if(mouseSpeed >= 8000)
                {
                    score += 1 * 5;
                }

            }

            //Update lastPost
            lastPos = Input.mousePosition;

            //Update timeToGo
            timeToGo = Time.fixedTime + 0.2f;
        }


    }

}
```